Homotopy between $f,g,h$
I am wondering if these functions are homotopy
$$f,g,h : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$$
where
$f(x)=e^{ix} , g(x) = 1 , h(x) = e^{2ix}$.
I already found the homotopy between $f$ and $g$.
It's $$H:\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$$
$H(x,t) = e^{i(1-t)x}$ and then I get what I wanted so $H(x,0)=e^{ix} , H(x,1) = 1 $, because $e^{i(1-1)x}=1$.
Now I'm wondering because I can do the same to the function $g$ and $h$ and get the same result, but I'm a bit confused. Is that right, given the function $h$ spins two times? Can somebody explain to me if my thoughts are correct or there is just a homotopy between those functions, and I don't have to worry about function h spinning two times?

Hint: Any two functions from a contractible space are homotopic to each other.

thanks, that's very helpful to know!
